# How to find specific text in a file with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, virtualbox

in general, the script is designed to search for all virtual machines running on Windows.

I'd like to find all the specific text files, it's exactly OSType="Win..." My problem is that I don't know how to make it find words that contain OSType="Win..." The problem is that it's written with "" in the file. This is my code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\*vbox -recurse |  Select-String -Pattern 'OSType="Windows7_64"' -List | Select Path | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\Public\ProcessKurdeExecuted.txt
```

Using * or % does not work

```
...Select-String -Pattern 'OSType="Windows*"'...
...Select-String -Pattern 'OSType="Windows%"'...
```

Comment: Assuming that youre on Windows get-childitem will deliver you the names of the files. If you want to filter on them, use get-childitem xxx | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*test'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation about regular expression is https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7

You should try

```
...Select-String -Pattern 'OSType="Windows.*"'...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
$OSType = 'OSType="Windows*'
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\*vbox -recurse |  Select-String -Pattern $OSType -List | Select Path | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\Public\ProcessKurdeExecuted.txt
```